# load content and then load the corresponding images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have bunch of 10 contacts to be shown . I want first to load the contacts so that the user can see the information and then corresponding images .

I have the following HTML

```
<table id="contactsTable" data-role="listview" data-dividertheme="c">
<tr><td>
<table id="imagesTable" data-role="listview" data-dividertheme="c"></table>
</td><td>
<table id="displayNamesTable" data-role="listview" data-dividertheme="c"></table>
</table>
</div>
```

But when i load the content through json , the content keeps shifting down as the images are being loaded .I am not sure how to handle it . Right now body on load i have a js function which parses the contacts,displays the contacts and then parses the images .
Thanks all .

Comment: Your markup seems to be a litte odd, why do you have "<tr>" tags outside of your table?

Comment: It's a nested table.  Evil things but valid markup (=

Comment: I am new to web apps . My idea is to have a master table .Create row , column and then have the table , create another column for images .Note:i want both the images and contact display names in the same row .

Comment: so you want all the photos show up once at a time when they are loaded?

Comment: i want to load the content , then load the images after the text content is loaded .so that the page is displayed faster and does not wait till all images are loaded .

Answer (score 3):

If you give the images width and height attributes they won't change size when the image data arrives.